# Possible states for two electrons in the helium atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, quantum-spin, pauli-exclusion-principle

Consider the helium atom with two electrons, but ignore coupling of angular momenta, relativistic effects, etc.

The spin state of the system is a combination of the triplet states and the singlet state. I will denote a linear combination of the three triplet states as $\lvert\chi_+\rangle$ (because it's symmetrical under exchange of electrons) and $\lvert\chi_-\rangle$ the singlet state (because it's anti-symmetric).

Then, the orbital state of the electrons. Suppose one electron is in the state $\lvert\phi_a\rangle$; the other in the state $\lvert\phi_b\rangle$. The orbital state of the system is:

$$ \lvert\phi_{\pm}\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \left (\lvert\phi_a\rangle\lvert\phi_b\rangle \pm \lvert\phi_b\rangle\lvert\phi_a\rangle \right )$$

Because the overal state $\lvert\psi\rangle$ of the electrons must be anti-symmetric, is it correct to construct it as following:

$$\lvert\psi\rangle = \lvert\phi_{\pm}\rangle \lvert\chi_{\mp}\rangle \text{  ?}$$

Comment: Tex tip of the day: while `|` and `\lvert` may produce the same symbol in your documents, the [latter is favored](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/498) because it explicitly is the left delimiter. Besides, MathJax renders the latter better, making for nicer-looking kets on this site :)

Comment: look at [marty-green having-trouble-counting-spin-states](http://marty-green.blogspot.pt/2013/05/having-trouble-counting-spin-states.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two electrons your are right!
The absolute must is for the total state to be anti-symmetric. Technically, this means that the total wave-function must belong to a one-dimensional representation of the permutation group such that  each permutation is represented by either +1 or -1 depending on it's parity.

You can ask about permutational symmetry separately for the spin part and the orbital part. If there number of electrons $n>2$, then the orbital part and the spin part may belong to these may belong to more complicated (e.g., more than one-dimensional) representations of the permutations group, those get classified by [Young tableux.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau).There are rules how to combine two "conjugate"(not sure if this is mathematically correct term) representations to construct the total wave-function anti-symmetric under any odd permutation. For $n=2$ these rules reduce to a simple product as you quote. For more on this you can consult Landau and Lifshitz, Quantum Mechanics (The Course of Theoretical Physics vol.III).

There is also a systematic connection between the representations of the permutation group for the spin part and the $SU(2)$ of the spin. Unfortuntally, I can't find the refernce which I  have learn this from (hopefully others can help).

Comment: Thanks! I was just asked to do this in an exercise and while what I did seemed intuitively obvious, I just wanted to make sure.

The case for $n>2$ seems really complicated, though.